# Flutter: I can't remove incoming Firebase notifications programmatically

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter

I have an incoming Firebase notification coming to my phone and if the user does not click on it and the user re-opens the app, I want the Android notification to be removed programmatically by tag and id_notification received from the notification payload.

I have used the Firebase_messaging "^1.0.1" Flutter plugin and the MessageHandler for incoming message works.

To remove the notification I have used a platform channel:

```
private boolean removeNotification(String tag, int idNotifica) {
    boolean result = false;
    NotificationManager notifManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notifManager.cancel(tag, idNotifica);
    result = true;
    return result;
  }
```

but it doesn't work or rather the notification can't be removed and a PlatformException occurs.

After I have an incoming Firebase notification coming to my phone, I run this platform channel code to see StatusBarNotification:

```
  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
  public String  getInfoAllNotification() {
    String info = "";
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    StatusBarNotification[] barNotifications = 
notificationManager.getActiveNotifications();
    for(StatusBarNotification notificationInStatusBar: barNotifications) {
      Notification n = notificationInStatusBar.getNotification();
      Bundle b = n.extras;
      if (b != null) {
        for (String key : b.keySet()) {
          Object value = b.get(key);
          info = info + String.format("%s %s ; ", key, value!=null?value.toString():"");
        }
        info = info + String.format("id_notification %s ;", notificationInStatusBar.getId());
        info = info + String.format("key %s ;", 
notificationInStatusBar.getKey());
        info = info + String.format("groupKey %s ;",notificationInStatusBar.getGroupKey());
        info = info + String.format("tag %s ;",notificationInStatusBar.getTag());
        info = info + String.format("postTime %s ;", notificationInStatusBar.getPostTime());
      }
    }
    return info;
  }
```

and I noticed id_notification is always 0 as shown below:

```
   FIRST NOTIFICATION
android.title this is a title ; 
android.subText  ; 
android.template android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle ; 
android.showChronometer false ; 
android.icon Icon(typ=RESOURCE pkg=com.XXX.firebase id=0x7f090000) ; 
android.text this is a body ; 
android.progress 0 ; 
android.progressMax 0 ; 
android.showWhen true ; 
android.rebuild.applicationInfo ApplicationInfo{23547cf com.XXX.firebase} ; 
android.rebuild.contentView true ; 
android.bigText this is a body ; 
android.infoText  ; 
android.originatingUserId 0 ; 
android.progressIndeterminate false ; 
android.rebuild true ; 
android.rebuild.bigView true ; 
id_notification 0 ;
key 0|com.XXX.firebase|0|2|10059 ;groupKey 0|com.XXX.firebase|0|2|10059 ;
tag 2 ;
postTime 1530639629519 ;

    SECOND NOTIFICATION
android.title this is a title ; 
android.subText ; 
android.template android.app.Notification$BigTextStyle ; 
android.showChronometer false ; 
android.icon Icon(typ=RESOURCE pkg=com.XXX.firebase id=0x7f090000) ; 
android.text this is a body ; 
android.progress 0 ; 
android.progressMax 0 ; 
android.showWhen true ; 
android.rebuild.applicationInfo ApplicationInfo{5aad55c com.XXX.firebase} ; 
android.rebuild.contentView true ; 
android.bigText this is a body ; 
android.infoText  ; 
android.originatingUserId 0 ; 
android.progressIndeterminate false ; 
android.rebuild true ; 
android.rebuild.bigView true ; 
id_notification 0 ;
key 0|com.XXX.firebase|0|1|10059 ;
groupKey 0|com.XXX.firebase|0|1|10059 ;
tag 1 ;
postTime 1530639593190 ;
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.